# Stackwalker has less frames than stacktrace has elements

Tags: java, stack-trace, java-9

I was experimenting a bit with the Stackwalking API of Java 9 and noticed that the frames collected are less than the ones given by the actual stack trace. I was wondering whether it is possible to get an identical number of frames and elements?

Have a look at the following test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    NaughtyBusiness nb = new NaughtyBusiness();
    try {
        //This method throws an exception
        nb.callMeForGoodTime(NaughtyBusiness.AlcoholTolerance.LOW);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = e.getStackTrace();

        StackWalker stackWalker = StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES);
        List<StackWalker.StackFrame> frames = 
                            stackWalker.walk(stackFrameStream -> stackFrameStream.collect(toList()));
       
        System.out.println(frames);
    }
}
```

Now if I debug the code I see the following:

[image]

The first obvious difference, is the number of StacktraceElements vs StackFrames (26 vs 23). More surprisingly though, the missing frames (marked in red) are the ones that are actually interesting, i.e. from my custom code, whereas the green part that is shared among both is just boilerplate.

The question therefore is, how am I able to get the "missing" frames with the StackWalking API? I've tried the 3 options `SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES`, `RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE` and `SHOW_REFLECT_FRAMES` but none worked.

Comment: You called StackWalker.getInstance from the `test()` method, so of course that is the first StackFrame it returns.  `walk` has no knowledge whatsoever of your caught exception.

Comment: I'm confused, where else should I call it from? Maybe I'm not understanding the purpose of this tool?

Comment: If you want an identical sequence of stack frames, you need to call `walk` from the same method which throws the exception;  that is, `playStupidGamesWinStupidPrizes`.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I didn't realize  what the API was meant for. If you formulate your comments into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `StackWalker.walk` method builds stack frames from the point where it was called.  In this case, you called it from the `test()` method, so it builds a sequence of stack frames starting with that method.

StackWalker doesn’t know about your caught exception at all.  The exception was thrown from a different place, namely the `NaughtyBusiness.playStupidGamesWinStupidPrizes` method, which is why its stack frames are different.

To get StackWalker frames which are identical to the exception's stack frames, you need to call `StackWalker.walk` from the same method which threw the exception.

Comment: To be more precise, you must call it from the same method where the exception was *constructed* or its `fillInStackTrace()` method has been called the last time. Usually, this is close to the spot where the exception will be thrown (the first time), but if you re-throw it from the `test()` method, it won’t change the recorded stack trace.